# C#: find current process

Tags: c#

How to get currently running application without using a system process?

Comment: Seriously, more detail required. How about a bit of background and a lengthier question so that we can offer the best answers. And please spell currently correctly...

Comment: @shhnap: come on, it's a nice Saturday, the sun is shining and there is a reasonable answer. Please remove your (factually incorrect) comment.

Comment: I thought only doctors have God Complex, but bigger complex exists with programmers, you are right David, people here are with absolute great ego. Poor guy got -4 for an absolute valid question. +1 for correct question from me.

Comment: @Akash: agree... can thank the rep system for the egos.

Comment: What do you mean, "currently running application"? Running on which processor of a multi-processor system? On my dev box at work, there are often four currently running applications; or the same application could be currently running on four threads. Please take the time to do better than a one-line question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on what you look for. If you are interested in the assembly that is calling you,then you can use [GetCallingAssembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getcallingassembly.aspx). You could also use [GetExecutingAssembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getexecutingassembly.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses("MACHINEHAME")
```

Answer (score 0):

Slight misconception here.  On any given machine there can be multiple current running process.  Consider the case where the machine has multiple CPU's.  It's possible, and in fact likely, that each CPU will have at least a separate thread running on it.  There is a very good chance that at any given time the number of processes currently running on the machine will be close to the number of processors on the system.

In the case of a single processor the act of getting the current running process is redundant.  It will simply be your application.

If you want to investigate processes running on the current machine without using the Process class, you can PInvoke into the Process32First and Process32Next system calls.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using .NET, whatever mechanism you end up using, make sure that you pay attention to .NET code access security. Read MSDN documentation to see if the class, method(s) you're using requires full-trust or not. This may be an issue if your app is supposed to run in partial trust or less privileged trust environment.